# Is there a replacement for config.ini for C#?

Tags: c#, configuration

I want to create a `config.ini` that exist in Java for C#?

Is there a way?

I discovered I have to create an `App.config` file.

But after creating the `App.config`, how do I use C# to read the add key?

This `App.config` is mainly for dynamic file path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your project, add reference to System.Configuration assembly then use such code to read the value of specific `appSetting` from the config based on its key:

```
string value = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key"];
```

Comment: when i add the code above, the ConfigurationManager is highlighted in red. How can I resolve it?

Comment: Have you added reference to System.Configuration assembly to your project? Via Visual Studio, just right click the project and choose Add Reference, it will be there under the first tab.

Answer (score 3):

For general application settings, you would store them in the `<appSettings>` element:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="MySetting" value="Hello World" />
</appSettings>
```

You can then read the settings using the `ConfigurationManager` or `WebConfigurationManager` class, e.g.:

```
string mySettings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MySetting"];
```

For non-web projects, add a reference to System.Configuration.dll

Answer (score 0):

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["settigs1"] = "value1";
```

Please, try search answer for you question in Google or Bing like [this](http://www.bing.com/search?q=msdn%20how%20to%20use%20app.config%20in%20c#&go=&form=QBRE&filt=all.)